# Pattern to deploy AWS Beanstalk in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been following this guide:

https://deliciousbrains.com/scaling-laravel-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-3-setting-elastic-beanstalk/

However I am stuck at this point.

Not in terms of something not working, but in how it should be done properly. Which app I should deploy?

Is is the development app that is tested and deployed? Do I create another instance in AWS that will be only used to deploy ready apps? What is the pattern to follow?

At the moment I have local development server which runs on my PC, and also 1 Development instance EC2 on AWS. Do I need more than that on top of Elastic beanstalk?

Please advice me! Thanks!

Comment: A question should be self-contained, meaning that links should be used as a reference and shouldn't be needed in order to write an answer. The reason for this is that links are often unreliable (they change, becomes unavailable, are dependent on an external service that may be down at some point, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern is the one that best fits your need. You're not just looking for a pattern, but an architecture. I'll try to help you with the information you provided.

First it is important that you really understand what Beanstalk is and how it works. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html

Answering your question, applications are typically placed in the beanstalk for scalable production, but nothing prevents you from setting up development environments for testing, too.

You do not need to create an instance to deploy, you can deploy from your own local machine, using the console, cli, or api. Look:

Console: https://sa-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home

EB Cli: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html

API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/Welcome.html

Having said that, I will cite a very useful scenario in several cases:

- You create a beanstalk application from the console or cli and configure the integration with AWS CodeCommit. CodeCommit will prevent you from having to send the whole project to each deploy.
- You create an instance of amazon to perform the implantation. This instance has a git repository of your project, it gets committed to the beanstalk environment settings (environment variables for example), and deploy to beanstalk using CodeCommit.

This scenario is very useful for a team project for beanstalk because you can use the deployment instance to hide sensitive details and configure deploy patterns.